# найти навешенный обработчик

Tags: javascript, jquery

Имеем элемент с навешенным на нём обработчиком `$(el).on('click', function() {/* содержимое анонимной функции */})`, как найти этот обработчик 
в мозиле `event` не указывает , может есть какой способ найти что обрабатывает элемент

Comment: `$(el).on('click', function() {/* содержимое анонимной функции */})` - эта запись говорит о том, что код обработчика перед Вами. Как Вы поняли, что обработчик назначен имеено так?

Comment: @Дмытрык насколько я понимаю в таком случае в браузере может не отображаться какой обработчик стоит на кнопке , нежели через onclick ,если я что-то не так понимаю , исправьте меня. во всяком случае на кнопке обработчика не стоит , но что-то его где-то обрабатывает, и нужно его найти

Comment: что делает обработчик? Изменяет HTML, стили; отправляет Ajax? Поставьте breakpoint на это изменение и браузер покажет Вам обработчик

Answer (score 0):

В консоле, на нужном элементе кликните ПКМ и выберите пункт, который соответствует результату работы обработчика
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0):

В общем случае узнать это проблематично.

Если используется нативный `addEventListener`, то узнать через `DevTool`s в хроме можно во вкладке `Event Listeners`.

Если навесили через `jQuery`, то узнать уже сложнее, потому что он создает обертку.

Если используются различные фреймворки, такие как `Angular`, `Vue`, `React` то узнать очень-очень сложно.

[image: Просмотр событий на элементе]

```js
btn.addEventListener('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
$('#btnJQ').on('click', function() {
  console.log('click');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="btn">test</button>
<button id="btnJQ">test jq</button>
```

Comment: так вот в том то и дело что event в браузере не показывает а обработчик срабатывает

Comment: У jQuery есть другой способ навесить обработчик. Поищите событие на родителях данного элемента, вплоть до body.